# Not able to receive request on jsp page

Tags: java, ajax, jsp

I am not able to receive request on jsp page which i send from html page.

I verified on Chrome's `Inspect element` that request was successfully send, and the  i noted the Request URL and i found that url was reachable( and correct).
I can say this because i pasted this url in browser and the resulting page that opened from Request URL was my jsp page.
So i could not figure out why and where i am making mistake, so that request is not going to jsp.

Some relevant piece of code:

html content

```
var url = "test.jsp";
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Inspect element's Network tab content:

```
Request URL: /MusicShopping/test.jsp
( http://localhost:14443 before /MusicShopping too)
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

Green ball before 200 appeared

jsp file contain only line of plain text.
(If i manually copy paste request url in browser my jsp page is displayed).

Please let me know where can be the problem

Comment: It sounds like you tried all of the usual tests to isolate the problem. How do you know the page isn't being reached?

Comment: @JasonSperske because i could not see the output. I have `hello test` on the jsp page only. So according to me if same url as in Request url can point to jsp and print output if done manually then why it is not showing output in case of firing the request. This is the point that lead me to conclude that page is not being reached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the request is sent, but nothing is done with response. Did you register a callback for onreadystatechange of XMLHttpRequest so that, when your AJAX request state changes the callback method will run and there you can check for readyStatus 4 and 200 page status and parse the response.

Please have a look into [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}
```

Comment: No, i omitted the callback intentionally, because i thought jsp file is already sending some html code to display, so there should be no need for callback. Am i incorrect

Comment: You need a callback in order to do anything with the response of an Ajax request.

Comment: Jason is right. The problem with your code is JSP was sending the response, but you ignored it. If you are using AJAX, parsing and displaying the response is our duty. You already mentioned that in Network tab you saw 200 status for the JSP page. See the response for that particular request.

Comment: So now, i want only `Hello world` to be displayed on whole html page, then how can it be done. Because there is some previously existing data on the page.

Comment: Wrap your existing html content inside a div. Assign it some id example, say "d1". 
And now in the callback do this,
document.getElementById("d1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

Before AJAX request:

<div id="d1"><p> something is here</p></div>

After AJAX response is parsed and callback is executed:
<div id="d1">Hello world (your JSP page output)</div>